# Update a Deployment image in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I'm very new to Kubernetes and using k8s v1.4, Minikube v0.15.0 and Spotify maven Docker plugin.

The build process of my project creates a Docker image and push it directly into the Docker engine of Minikube.

The pods are created by the Deployment I've created (using replica set), and the strategy was set to `type: RollingUpdate`.

I saw this in the documentation:

> **Note**: a Deployment’s rollout is triggered if and only if the Deployment’s pod template (i.e. .spec.template) is changed.

I'm searching for an easy way/workaround to automate the flow:
Build triggered > a new Docker image is pushed (withoud version changing) > Deployment will update the pod > service will expose the new pod.

Comment: If you aren't changing the image at all, then there is no way to ensure that you get the new image in each pod, unless you set `ImagePullPolicy: Always` and kill each pod and have the deployment recreate it. However, if you are creating a new docker image every time, it would make sense to update the tag as well.

Comment: @AnirudhRamanathan 
As I'm not creating a "new" image every time, just updating the image, I will go with the first approach, so there is a way to kill the old pods automatically?

Comment: `ImagePullPolicy: Always` is not working with local images, so meanwhile i'm manually delete the pods with specific lable, then the replica set is creating them with the updated image.
wondering if there is any way to do it automatically.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

when not changing the container image name or tag you would just scale your application to 0 and back to the original size with sth like:

```
kubectl scale --replicas=0 deployment application
kubectl scale --replicas=1 deployment application
```

As mentioned in the comments already `ImagePullPolicy: Always` is then required in your configuration.

When changing the image I found this to be the most straight forward way to update the

```
kubectl set image deployment/application app-container=$IMAGE
```

Not changing the image has the downsite that you'll have nothing to fall back to in case of problems. Therefore I'd not suggest to use this outside of a development environment.

---

Edit: small bonus - keeping the scale in sync before and after could look sth. like:

```
replica_spec=$(kubectl get deployment/applicatiom -o jsonpath='{.spec.replicas}')
kubectl scale --replicas=0 deployment application
kubectl scale --replicas=$replica_spec deployment application
```

---

Cheers

Comment: there is a way to do the same with Kubernetes API?

Comment: Hello again - see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41792851/manage-replicas-count-for-deployment-using-kubernetes-api/41795286#41795286

Comment: Won't there be a downtime of your app, if you scale down and then up? If yes, how can i avoid downtime?

Comment: Yes there's be a downtime - that's an answer from 2017, there are other ways to trigger the update e.g. `kubectl rollout restart ...`

Answer (score 10):

Use the following functionality if you have atleast a 1.15 version

```
kubectl rollout restart deployment/deployment-name
```

Read more about it here [kubectl rollout restart](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#-em-restart-em-)

Comment: It's actually `kubectl rollout restart deploy <name>` for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious why you're not changing the image version (:

Another option (beside `kubectl rollout restart`) is to use [kubectl patch](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#patch):

```
kubectl patch deployment name -p "{\"spec\":{\"template\":{\"metadata\":{\"labels\":{\"version\":\"$BUILD_SHA_OR_DATE\"}}}}}}"
```

With this command you have the flexibility to change specific fields in the deployment spec like the *label selector*, pod label, environment variables etc'

(*) Another option that is more suitable for debugging but worth mentioning is to check in revision history of your rollout:

```
$ kubectl rollout history deployment my-dep
deployment.apps/my-dep
 
REVISION  CHANGE-CAUSE
2         <none>
4         <none>
5         <none>
6         <none>
11        <none>
12        <none>
```

And then returning to the previous revision by running:

```
 $kubectl rollout undo deployment my-dep --to-revision=11
```

And then returning back to the new one.

(**) The CHANGE-CAUSE is `<none>` because you should run the updates with the `--record` flag - like mentioned [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#updating-a-deployment):

```
kubectl set image deployment/nginx-deployment nginx=nginx:1.16.1 --record
```

(***) There is a [discussion](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/40422) regarding deprecating this flag.

Comment: In my case we are not changing the image version when deploying dev/staging environments from the same branch. The tag/version is just the branch slug. That way we can make cleanup easier and save space in the registry. But I'm all ears for better approaches :)

Comment: I recommend using the git commit (or the first 8 digits like I do) for image tags, this way you can find the corresponding commit very easily and you force k8s to get the correct version.
NOTE: if you are only changing the src of your application in the image the space taken in the registry will only be the size of the src, not the full size of the image again