# Manage replicas count for deployment using Kubernetes API

Tags: kubernetes

I want to change the number of replications (pods) for a **Deployment** using the Kubernetes API (v1beta1).

For now I'm able to increase the replicas from CLI using the command:

```
kubectl scale --replicas=3 deployment my-deployment
```

In the [Kubernetes API documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1.5/#replace-scale) it's mention that there is a PUT request to do the same

```
PUT /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/{namespace}/deployments/{name}/scale
```

but there is no example of how to do it.

I'm not sure what to send in the request body in order to perform the update.

Comment: Here is the link for client-go example -
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61653702/scale-deployment-replicas-with-kubernetes-go-client/63439093#63439093

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61653702/scale-deployment-replicas-with-kubernetes-go-client/63439093#63439093

Answer (score 18, accepted):

the easiest way is to retrieve the actual data first with:

```
GET /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/{namespace}/deployments/{name}/scale
```

This will give you an yaml or json object which you can modify and send back with the `PUT` request.

---

With curl the roundtrip look like this:

```
API_URL="http://kubernetes:8080/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/{namespace}/deployments/{name}/scale"
curl  -H 'Accept: application/json' $API_URL > scale.json
# edit scale.json
curl -X PUT -d@scale.json -H 'Content-Type: application/json' $API_URL
```

---

Alternatively you could just use a `PATCH` call:

```
PAYLOAD='[{"op":"replace","path":"/spec/replicas","value":"3"}]'
curl -X PATCH -d$PAYLOAD -H 'Content-Type: application/json-patch+json' $API_URL
```

Answer (score 5):

The previous solution didn't work for me on kubernetes 1.14. I had to use a different API endpoint. 
Here's the full example:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

set -e

NUMBER_OF_REPLICAS="$1"
CURRENT_NAMESPACE="$2"
DEPLOYMENT_NAME="$3"

KUBE_TOKEN=$(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)
KUBE_CACRT_PATH="/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt"

PAYLOAD="{\"spec\":{\"replicas\":$NUMBER_OF_REPLICAS}}"

curl --cacert $KUBE_CACRT_PATH \
     -X PATCH \
     -H "Content-Type: application/strategic-merge-patch+json" \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer $KUBE_TOKEN" \
     --data "$PAYLOAD" \
     https://$KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST/apis/apps/v1/namespaces/$CURRENT_NAMESPACE/deployments/$DEPLOYMENT_NAME
```

Note that the `$KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST` is automatically set by kubernetes inside the pods.