# Customizing autoscaling policy in Kubernetes

Tags: go, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, autoscaling

I am working on a project where we want to test an autoscaling algorithm which involves making a few changes to the default horizontal pod autoscaling algorithm on Kubernetes. Where should we make changes in the https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler repo so that we can test our algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

The Cluster-Autoscaler is pretty much a cluster auto scaling version which will scale the number of Nodes, in case any of below happens.

> - there are pods that failed to run in the cluster due to insufficient    resources
> - there are nodes in the cluster that have been    underutilized for an extended period of time and their pods can be    placed on other
>     existing nodes.

If you want a custom pod scaling algorithm, I would recommend doing it as a simple service that does just that and not to alter the Cluster Autoscaler. Here's a similar solution to your problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58447811/5617140

You can alter the service logic to suit your requirements. And it is probably a  good idea to use Kubernetes API to achieve scaling tasks.