# golang set replicas for kubernetes deployments

Tags: go, kubernetes, client-go

I'm trying to get a list of deployments in all namespaces and loop through each one of them to see if the deployment has a particular annotation. If the annotation is present, then I would like to reduce the number of replicas for that deployment to 0, and if the annotation is not present leave the deployment unchanged.

I'm new to go, so far I am able to list the deployments that have the annotation I'm looking for. But not sure how to set the replica count to 0. Please let me know if someone has any idea how to achieve that. Thanks.

This is what I have so far:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "path/filepath"

    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
    "k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd"
    "k8s.io/client-go/util/homedir"

    metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
)

func main() {
    config, err := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", filepath.Join(homedir.HomeDir(), ".kube", "config"))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    clientset, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    //Get list of deployments in all namespaces
    depl, err := clientset.AppsV1().Deployments("").List(context.Background(), metav1.ListOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    annotation := "CAN_BE_DELETED"

    //Loop through all deployments and see if the annotation is present
    for _, item := range depl.Items {
        annotationMap := item.Annotations

        _, isPresent := annotationMap[annotation]
        if isPresent {
            fmt.Printf("%v\n", item.Name)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [scale/client_test.go](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/d5e58631fd5bb96e6ea8e55a1eab352ad15cf2b7/scale/client_test.go)have demo `TestUpdateScale`

Comment: I was able to get it working using the solution provided here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61653702/scale-deployment-replicas-with-kubernetes-go-client