# Scaling and listing deployments via Kubernetes HTTP API?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to scale up/down some deployments over HTTP and also list the deployments on my cluster. I'm able to list pods, but can't figure out the deployments piece.

`http://localhost:8080/api/v1/namespaces/default/deployments`

```
{
    "kind": "Status",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {},
    "status": "Failure",
    "message": "the server could not find the requested resource",
    "reason": "NotFound",
    "details": {},
    "code": 404
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Deployments are in the `apps/v1` namespace, and you need to include `apps` in the URL.  The [API documentation for the "list deployments" endpoint](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#list-deployment-v1-apps) gives the URL as

```
GET /apis/apps/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/deployments
```

You can use the normal read-modify-write sequence to change the `replicas:` field in a deployment spec to scale it.

There is also [a dedicated endpoint to scale deployments](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#replace-scale-deployment-v1-apps), though it's slightly underdocumented.  [Manage replicas count for deployment using Kubernetes API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41792851/manage-replicas-count-for-deployment-using-kubernetes-api)
 suggests reading and patching the scale resource, or there is an example with a minimal JSON payload.